# HTML link with href that refers to text?

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

This is a simple yes or no question (probably no), googling didn't seem to give me a straight answer. Say you have a link that is

```
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">www.stackoverflow.com</a>
```

Is it possible to make something like

```
<a href=self.text>www.stackoverflow.com</a>
```

without using anything else (obviously, no scripts)? Is there any kind of shortcut?

Comment: Nope, no way to do that.

Comment: That's only possible with JavaScript, I'd imagine. Though, with CSS you could sort of do it the other way round, take the `href` attribute and make that the link text. (Though it wouldn't generate a clickable text, I think.)

Comment: @DavidThomas - A quick test shows that it generates clickable text in IE, Firefox, Opera and Safari, but not Chrome.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, you need to have both the `href` attribute and a value between the `a` tags. Without using any scripts, it's not possible to refer to its own contents.

Answer (score 0):

create an script/function for that

put a class to all of your anchors (i.e. "anchorTextAsHref" ), get all of them and modify the DOM structure,

just placing the text equals to whatever href has.

```
    let anchors=document.getElementsByClassName("anchorTextAsHref");
    for (let i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        anchors[i].text = anchors[i].href;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Use anchor link Useful Tips Section
Create a link to the "Useful Tips Section" inside the same document:

Visit the Useful Tips Section

Answer (score -3):

I think you're looking for the Anchor Tag .  You can use the syntax  to link to it, if you reference it by using a `<a href="link">` somewhere in the body.

Look here at the bottom for some examples:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: Nope, not looking for an anchor. Just looking for a way to get the href to equal the text. Thanks, though.

Comment: I was simply wondering if it was possible (without Javascript) to have a link's URL lifted from its text. The answer is no.