# How to use text itself as hyperlink in HTML?

Tags: html, href

How to use the text as hyperlink in HTML? Currently I use following line :

```html
<a href="www.google.com"> www.google.com </a>
```

but I think this is too repetitive. Is there any good approach to this? Is there any other way to tell html that the text itself is hyperlink?

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485074/html-link-with-href-that-refers-to-text) it's not possible without using any script.

Comment: Ok thanks. I apologise, I could not find that question. This is duplicate of that question. Thanks for the reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a shortcut. You just have to have the receptiveness, otherwise html won't know it's a link.